# quantmod - getQuote() - '403 Forbidden'

Tags: r

I found an answer to my own question (see below). Still need help.

In the same package, quantmod, there is an option called getSymbol.google.

Nevertheless,

If I use it to get Microsoft value, for example, it works all right

> getSymbols.google('MSFT', environment() , src="google", from = (Sys.Date() - 1))

[1] "MSFT"

But, I can´t make it work on a currency pair;

> getSymbols.google("GBPUSD", environment() , src="google", from = (Sys.Date() - 1))

Error in download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=GBPUSD&startdate=Nov+02,+2017&enddate=Nov+03,+2017&output=csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  :
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=GBPUSD&startdate=Nov+02,+2017&enddate=Nov+03,+2017&output=csv': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'

Any ideas?

Good morning,

Since the 1ts of November i´m having trouble with the function **getQuote** from Yahoo. Is a function inside the package "quantmod", which uses yahoo API to request the information.

The description of the function is as follows; **Fetch current stock quote(s) from specified source. At present this only handles sourcing quotes from Yahoo Finance, but it will be extended to additional sources over time.**

In r, i´m getting the following error; **"HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'"**

I´ve look on my browser and the error comes from the following error in Yahoo web page **"Fetch current stock quote(s) from specified source. At present this only handles sourcing quotes from Yahoo Finance, but it will be extended to additional sources over time."**

Does anybody know how to solve ir, or, any alternatives to the function getQuote()

Here is an example from RStudio

> getQuote("AAPL")
>   Error in download.file(paste("https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=",  : 
>     cannot open URL 'https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=d1t1l1c1p2ohgv'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In download.file(paste("https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=",  :
>     cannot open URL 'https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=d1t1l1c1p2ohgv': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

seems that yahoo has discontinued this service. Anyone aware of a alternative for yahoo (I'd rather not have to webscrape yahoo for this)

rob

Comment: I am trying with google finance, I´ll let you know if I find out something

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem... it's kludgey but as a workaround to get the end-of-day value, I have found this to work for now:

Instead of getQuote() to get the Last price (which doesn't seem to work from Yahoo anymore):

```
underlying<-"AAPL"
quote.last <-getQuote(underlying)$Last
```

I use "getSymbols" which still works-- throws it into a new data frame, and I pull out the value I want from that:

```
Hx<-getSymbols(underlying,from=Sys.Date()-1) # allows me to not have to retain the ticker name if I do this across many tickers
quote.last<-as.double(tail(Cl(get(Hx)),1)) # Closing price value from last row of data
rm(list=Hx) # throw away the temporary data frame with quote history
```

I'm sure the's a more elegant way to do it, but this is what fell out of my brain as a quick workaround that got it done... sadly that doesn't get things like the Bid and Ask that getQuote does.

Comment: Thanks DeltaVictorBravo, nevertheless, it still doesn´t work for Currency Pairs.

Also, as a shortcut for your function, try with getSymbols.google('AAPL', environment() , src='google'), it may help you.